# Using ArrayList in a sub-template on .jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, server

I have a JSP home page with a menu. I want that menu to be on multiple pages so I created a `menu.jsp` template. I imported, all static source code appears but the `<c:forEach />` tag is not picking it up. When I print (just put it plainly in the html) out my `${allCategories}` variable I get all the data correctly.

In a controller, I set `model.addAttribute("allCategories", categoryService.getPrimaryCategories());`

`home.jsp` where the categories were before is importing `<jsp:include page="menu.jsp"/>`

in `menu.jsp` I am unable to get `<c:forEach items="${allCategories}" var="category">` to work but when I just put `<p>${allCategories}</p>` at the beginning of the file it shows stuff like  `[Category(id=1281, name=Bundles, image=https://images...`
How do I get the data correctly in the sub-template so it works like directly on the page?

Comment: You could try using the JSP include directive. It is used to include a file during the translation phase. For example,   <%@ include file = "menu.jsp" >

Comment: @rickz would you like to post this as a correct answer? Works a treat :))) thanks bud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the JSP include directive. It is used to include a file during the translation phase. For example,

```
<%@ include file = "menu.jsp" >
```